# Why won't rpm/yum pick up the required packages when I list it specifically?

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum

I'm having a problem where using **rpm** and **yum** won't pick up the packages required for an update. I'm performing an upgrade of *main-package* from 16.1 to 16.2. If I do **yum upgrade**, I get this:

```
# yum upgrade
...
======================================================================================================
 Package                       Arch           Version                      Repository            Size
======================================================================================================
Updating:
 sub-package                   x86_64         1.1-455015.el7               privaterepo           29 k
 main-package                  noarch         16.2-460032.el7              privaterepo          1.9 M
...
```

If I run **yum upgrade main-package** I get this:

```
# yum upgrade main-package
======================================================================================================
 Package                        Arch            Version                   Repository             Size
======================================================================================================
Updating:
 main-package                   noarch          16.2-460032.el7           privaterepo           1.9 M

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================
```

It doesn't seem to think I need the new *sub-package*, even though the RPM suggests it does:

```
# rpm -q --requires -p main-package-16.2-460032.el7.noarch.rpm  | grep -i sub-package
sub-package >= 1.1

# rpm -qa | grep sub-package
sub-package-1.0-455013.el7.x86_64
```

Based on what I see, when I **yum upgrade main-package**, it should see that it needs *sub-package >= 1.1* and get it as well. I should add that the install works fine. It's as if **rpm** and **yum** are completely ignoring the requirement that *main-package* needs version 1.1 of *sub-package*.

**EDIT:**

Here is what rpm shows about dependencies:

```
# rpm -q --provides -p sub-package-1.1-455015.el7.x86_64.rpm 
sub-package
sub-package = 1.1-455015.el7
sub-package(x86-64) = 1.1-455015.el7

# rpm -q --requires -p main-package-16.2-460032.el7.noarch.rpm  | grep sub-package
sub-package >= 1.1
```

Here is the older *sub-package* that's already installed:

```
# rpm -q --provides sub-package
sub-package
sub-package = 1.0-455013.el7
sub-package(x86-64) = 1.0-455013.el7
```

Here is the relevant information in my spec file:

```
$ grep sub-package main-package.spec
Requires: sub-package >= 1.1

$ head -n4 sub-package.spec
Summary: sub-package (...)
Name: sub-package
Version: 1.1
Release: %{BUILD_NUMBER}%{?dist}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've been doing some more digging, One thing I noticed is that *sub-package* is listed twice if I *rpm -q --whatprovides sub-package* where the other dependencies that it picks up fine are only listed once.

Comment: It looks like `sub-package 1.1-455015.el7` is *available*, but what is currently installed? If it is `1.1-somethingelse`, then the requirements are met.

Comment: # rpm -qa | grep sub-package
sub-package-1.0-455013.el7.x86_64

Comment: That was there the whole time? Don't know how I missed it... sorry, no idea then.

Comment: did you try updating using rpm (to see if this is a yum problem): copy your main-package-16.2...rpm to your target machine; then do: `rpm -Uvh main-package-16.2...rpm`. If that works without rpm complaining about sub-package-1.1 missing; that means the problem lies in your spec files.

Comment: rpm doesn't work on it's own. Any ideas what might be wrong in the spec file? _main-package_ has the line `Requires: sub-package >= 1.1` and _sub-package_ has the line `Version: 1.1`. I included more information in the main post.

Comment: I wonder what will happen when you answer Yes to "Do you want to proceed?" question. Do you get some error, or yum will happily install just that main-package without the sub-package?

Comment: yum happily installs it without the new version of _sub-package_ which causes _main-package_ to break.

Comment: `rpm -q --provides sub-package` shows that it provides unversioned `sub-package`. This satisfies the dependency.

Comment: Aha! That was it! Somewhere in the bowels of the spec was a **Provides: sub-package**. If you want to write up an answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwser, thanks to @alvits, is that I had

```
Provides: sub-package
```

in the *sub-package* spec file. The hint comes from this line:

```
# rpm -q --provides -p sub-package-1.1-455015.el7.x86_64.rpm 
sub-package
sub-package = 1.1-455015.el7
sub-package(x86-64) = 1.1-455015.el7
```

The first line of output tells *rpm* that my version of *sub-package* satisfies all version.